# Change nginx Root Directory at Scheduled Time

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

*Let me quickly preface this by saying that I'm not a server administrator, so it's quite possible that I may be asking the "wrong" questions here.*

---

I have a situation where we have a domain that will serve static files (HTML, images, etc.) that are configured and built by an existing, separate application. At certain scheduled datetimes, we will need the content of the sites to change to a different set of static files.

Since the files will all be prepared ahead of time, I was wondering if it was possible for nginx to be able to "switch" the root directory to direct traffic to the appropriate place based on these scheduled datetimes.

So if there were a series of directories maybe like this:

- `/www.example.com-20160701000000/content/public`
- `/www.example.com-20160708000000/content/public`
- `/www.example.com-20160801120000/content/public`

And then the configuration would say that from 1 July 2016 00:00:00 through 7 July 2016 23:59:59, the site root for www.example.com would be `/www.example.com-20160701000000/content/public`, and so forth.

Some other things I've looked into:

- Some form of middleware like PHP, but I want to avoid this for portability.
- SSI doesn't really seem like an option. It seems like I'd have one root directory and in the index.html, the contents would be something like `<!--# include file="www.example.com-$datestamp/content/public/index.html" -->` but it seems like I'd have to do this for every page maybe? I'm also not sure how it would work if the page names are different between versions.
- A cron job or something else that either moves files or edits a file at the appropriate time, this just seems like a really bad potential failure point.

**So tl;dr, can nginx be configured in some way to have root directories that are active for a domain at different scheduled times? Or is there a better approach to this problem that I'm not aware of?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` has variables called `$time_iso8601` and `$time_local` which you could use to construct a dynamic root. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_time_iso8601) for details.

One approach would be to construct your rules as a map and set the `root` directive appropriately using the mapped variable or named captures. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

I tested the concept using this:

```
map $time_iso8601 $root {
    default          /usr/local/www/test;
    ~^2016-06-2[0-9] /usr/local/www/test/test-20160625;
}

server {
    root $root;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is perfect: exactly the kind of direction I was hoping for. Thank you!